# How to take screenshot of full webpage in Electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron

I was try `BrowserWindow.capturePage` but this function take screenshot of only visible page.
I try to google, but didn't find how to take screenshot of full webpage in Electron app?

Comment: Are you using the Screenshot Service?

Comment: Are you trying to take a screenshot of the electron app ? or the entire screen ?

Comment: I need to capture entire web page loaded in BrowserWindow element. Not only visible area of page.

Comment: @Pavel this article may be useful: http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/280/creating-screenshots-of-your-app-or-the-screen-in-electron-framework

Answer (score 3):

As I knew from electron doc, `webContents.capturePage` only return the screenshot of visible area, **additional**, if the size of web page is larger than the screen, the result will miss the overflowed content

**【Solution】**

**1. find a node module to transfer DOM to Image**

> suggest **[html-to-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image)**

**2. load it into the target webpage**

> via **`preload`**

```js
  // mainProcess
  const testWin = new BrowserWindow({
    ...
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, '../preload.js'),
    },
    ...
  });

  // preload.js
  const htmlToImage = require('html-to-image');

  if (window) {
    window.htmlToImage = htmlToImage;
  }
```

**3. prepare execute JS content**

```js
// captureWebPageJS
(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      if (window.htmlToImage) {
        const htmlToImage = window.htmlToImage;
        const $body = document.querySelectorAll('body')[0];

        htmlToImage.toJpeg($body).then(resolve).catch(reject);
      } else {
        reject(new Error('no htmlToImage module found!'));
      }
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
})();
```

**4. convert DOM to image and auto-open**

```js
const previewImgUrl = path.join(__dirname, 'preview-capture-image.jpg');
const imgUrlViaBase64 = await testWin.webContents.executeJavaScript(captureWebPageJS, true);

fs.writeFileSync(previewImgUrl, String(imgUrlViaBase64).replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ''), {
  encoding: 'base64',
});
// { shell } = require('electron');
shell.openPath(previewImgUrl);
```

OK, everything has been done!

Answer (score 0):

I used this library [https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenshot-desktop]
this works very well, when you call the lib method returned by the bufer array, you can save the file to a temporary directory and get an absolute link to the screenshot. here's one thing - when you call the screenshot method, it takes the screenshot itself to the clipboard